# Get the output of `:map` into a buffer

Tags: vim

I'd like to get the output of an argumentless `:map` call so that I can use vim's search functionality to look for mappings.

I found about `:redir`, which redirects the output of ex commands into a variable, register, or file, but it doesn't seem to work for map, which must be outputting the mappings in some different way from what, for example `:echo 'hello world'` does.

Comment: I just tried that `:redir` actually worked. I executed three command in sequence `:redir @a`, `:map`, and `:redir END`. Then I just pasted the output of `:map` into a buffer by `"ap`. See [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `:redir` for that. Here's a oneliner that uses the default register:

```
:redir @" | silent map | redir END | new | put!
```

Comment: It didn't work with the normal register but this did: `  redir @a | silent map | redir END | new | put a `