# Making a new, modified buffer closable with just bd

Tags: vim

In [Get the output of `:map` into a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251647/get-the-output-of-map-into-a-buffer/28252238#28252238)
I learned I can use

```
  redir @a | silent map | redir END | new | silent put a
```

to view the output of map in a buffer, which is convenient because it's long and I want to be able to navigate it vim-style.

However, the new buffer requires `:bd!` for closing, because it's modified.
Is it possible to set it so it's closable with just `:bd`?

(I know it's just one character but I'd rather be careful with `:bd!` because I don't want to accidentally lose actual data (map output is disposable))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command opens a new scratch buffer in a new vertical window and populates it with the output of the given Ex command:

```
function! Redir(cmd)
    redir => output
    execute a:cmd
    redir END
    vnew
    setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
    call setline(1, split(output, "\n"))
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Redir silent call Redir(<f-args>)
```

You can close the window or delete the buffer however you want.

Usage:

```
:Redir map
```

Comment: Very neat. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Add this one line to

```
set hidden
```

your `vimrc`.